Does the "acks" configuration apply to the 'sender' thread of the KafkaProducer client?
I have a couple of questions regarding the async nature of the KafkaProducer client which were unanswered by the official documentation.
Background:

I am working on a project where I need to log some data into a kafka topic. I need to ensure that there is minimum latency on the main thread while adding this additional publishing step in the logic.
In our existing config for the KafkaProducer, we do not explicitly mention the acks value, and upon reading the documentation I understood that it is set to all by default.
This raised a concern wherein the ask was to set the acks config to 0 so that the application thread calling send() will not wait for the acknowledgement of all the partitions.

What I tried:

Upon reading this wonderful document by Adobe and the official doc itself, I understood the role of the internal buffer, it was clear that KafkaProducer send() is asynchronous and does not block the calling thread till the records are persisted in the partitions.
In the code, I increased the linger time to a high amount to see that the main thread isn't waiting for the message to be persisted in the partitions from the buffer.

Problems:

I'm still a little iffy about how the acks config works and want to be sure before I commit to my decision. Does the acks config apply to the sender thread(the thread which takes the batch of messages from the internal buffer and writes to all the paritions) only? Regardless of the value of this, it does not affect the main thread unless we're doing a blocking operation such as Future.get() from the main thread.
We had another issue where we see the time taken to complete the kafka produce operation in our dashboard during peak traffic was spiking at times. We were under the impression that since we use a shared cluster housing our topics, during peak traffic the response time is bound to spike. After reading these docs I have some suspects related to the response time spike:

The start-time of the metric is before the send() function and the end-time
is after the RecordMetadata is returned and the metrics publishing function is called in a doOnSuccess or a doOnError bloc of the calling thread.
Based on this design I assumed that whatever time is published is the time taken to perform the series of steps(i.e, calculate Producer Metadata, compute the partition, serialize etc) until the message lands in the internal-buffer and not the time taken for the message to write to the partition itself. Please validate this statement!
I'm now trying to figure out what could be the issue for the spike in response time, and I'm assuming it is an internal issue within the application.

Could it be that when the send() function is complete, the sent messages in the internal buffer should be cleared and if this is a blocking operation, it could keep the application threads waiting to write to the buffer?
If this is true then would increasing the linger or batch size help with this issue since the clearing operation of the internal buffer won't happen so frequently?







Based on this design I assumed that whatever time is published is the
time taken to perform the series of steps(i.e, calculate Producer
Metadata, compute the partition, serialize etc) until the message
lands in the internal-buffer and not the time taken for the message to
write to the partition itself

This statement in not true. According to ack config documentation:

acks=0 If set to zero then the producer will not wait for any
acknowledgment from the server at all. The record will be immediately
added to the socket buffer and considered sent.

So Callback will be notified after the record was put into socket, not internal buffer
Also send() method is not guaranteed to be completely non-blocking even though it returns Future. You can find this code in the KafkaProducer.doSend() code:

accumulator.append(..., remainingWaitMs, ...);

So send() may actually block if internal buffer is full. It might happen, for example, if you are producing messages faster than network thread sends them to the broker (even without waiting any acknowledgment)

So Callback will be notified after the record was put into socket, not internal buffer.
For the above statement, this impacts the application main thread only if we're waiting for the callback right? If we write Future.get() to make the send() operation blocking and wait for the callback

yes, the moment when callback is notified doesn't impact your main thread, until you are doing some explicit blocking logic, including waiting the future. However, send() might still be blocking for the provided at the end reason
